# Pandas drop rows not in labels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas DataFrames (A and B) with overlapping indexes. I want to drop the rows in DataFrame B for which that index value doesn't exist in DataFrame A.

I have looked into Pandas [drop](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) method for DataFrames but it drops the columns with the given labels, I would like to drop the columns for which there are not given labels.

For now I managed to do this with:

```
B.drop(B.drop(A.index).index)
```

But this is clearly not the best way to do it (not efficient or readable). Is there a better way?

**Example:**

DataFrame **A**:

```
   index       col1  
     1       some_data    
     2       some_data    
     3       some_data   
     4       some_data
```

DataFrame **B**:

```
   index       col2  
     1       other_data    
     2       other_data    
     3       other_data   
     4       other_data   
     5       other_data   
     6       other_data
```

I want to obtain DataFrame **B'**:

```
   index       col2  
     1       other_data    
     2       other_data    
     3       other_data   
     4       other_data
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print B.index.isin(A.index)
[ True  True  True  True False False]

print B[B.index.isin(A.index)]
             col2
index            
1      other_data
2      other_data
3      other_data
4      other_data
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `difference` to find the row labels that are not in the other df index:

```
In [6]:
df2.drop(df2.index.difference(df1.index))

Out[6]:
             col2
index            
1      other_data
2      other_data
3      other_data
4      other_data
```

Answer (score 3):

```
A = pd.DataFrame( data=np.random.rand( 4 ) , index=range( 4 ) )
#           0
# 0  0.776067
# 1  0.782038
# 2  0.588616
# 3  0.306854

B = pd.DataFrame( data=np.random.rand( 6 ) , index=range( 1 , 7 ) )
#          0
# 1  0.732170
# 2  0.925673
# 3  0.438083
# 4  0.735083
# 5  0.125201
# 6  0.610408

B.loc[ A.index ]

#           0
# 0       NaN
# 1  0.732170
# 2  0.925673
# 3  0.438083
```

`A.index` will give you the index of things you want and then `.loc` allows you to pick the data you want. Above I got a NaN. I'm on version 0.13.1 so I may be a bit out of sync with the most recent 0.18

Comment: The only problem here is that if A's index has row labels that are not in B then this will raise a `KeyError`

Comment: didn't get an error on this, just got NaN's in those cases

Comment: OK I expected this to raise a key error, maybe the behaviour has changed

Comment: @EdChum `KeyError` will be raised if only none of the index in A is available in B, otherwise even if there is atleast one index matching it will not raise error. And for those index where there is no match, it will return `NaN`

Comment: @Abbas I guess that makes some sense that it doesn't bork because 1 label isn't present

Answer (score 2):

Use to methods:

- DataFrame.ix(some_index): allows you to subset a DataFrame on an index
- DataFrame.index.intersection(some_index): returns the intersection of indices

#### Setup

```
In [1]: A = pd.DataFrame([['some_data']] * 4, index=range(1, 5), columns=['col1'])

In [2]: A
Out[2]:
        col1
1  some_data
2  some_data
3  some_data
4  some_data

In [3]: B = pd.DataFrame([['some_data']] * 6, index=range(1, 7), columns=['col2'])

In [4]: B
Out[4]:
        col2
1  some_data
2  some_data
3  some_data
4  some_data
5  some_data
6  some_data
```

#### Solution

```
In [5]: B.ix[A.index.intersection(B.index)]
Out[5]:
        col2
1  some_data
2  some_data
3  some_data
4  some_data
```